# React Typescript ESLint "extends" parsing error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint

I have a react typescript code that looks like the following in Button.tsx:

```
   import * as React from 'react';

   type ButtonOwnProps<E extends React.ElementType = React.ElementType> = {
     children?: React.ReactNode;
     variant?: 'contained' | 'outlined';
     as?: E;
   };
```

I am getting the following eslint error:

```
Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

  1 | import * as React from 'react';
  2 |
> 3 | type ButtonOwnProps<E extends React.ElementType = React.ElementType> = {
    |                       ^
  4 |   children?: React.ReactNode; eslint
```

Can anyone help me understand where I did wrong?

Comment: That looks like a Javascript error, not a error emitted by Typescript. You probably don't have the appropriate typescript plugins loaded for eslint.

Comment: You're right @Evert. I had to add [the right typescript plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin) to ESLint which sorted everything out.